# Can I directly use imagemagick in Heroku on node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm going to deploy my web app soon on Heroku (standard). So can I simply start using Imagemagick right off the bat or not? I already have it installed locally on my computer and obviously have the module required as well in my app.

So will it work exactly as it's working on my machine? like resizing images and getting the src path of images from specific folders like I have on my computer (I'm a newbie at deployment sorry).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use the latest version of Imagemagick on Heroku?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28423201/how-can-i-use-the-latest-version-of-imagemagick-on-heroku)

Answer (score 3):

You have to add the imagemagick buildpack on heroku:

heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick.git

And then you can use a library to call imagemagick